# Convert LinkedIn APIs time to a standard date in Python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

When I extract the time from LinkedIn, it's in this format

```
1374527684523
```

I dont know what format that is, but how do I convert it to normal time.

```
month day, year  hours:mins:seconds
```

Comment: Where do you get this string from? (LinkedIn API? Which call? Screen scraping? Where?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [LinkedIn Documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile), I see that they return milliseconds for the timestamps. To convert the milliseconds into a time format, you could do.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1374527684523/1000.0)
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23, 2, 44, 44, 523000)
```

To format it, you could do

```
>>> "{0} {1}, {2} {3}:{4}:{5}".format(date.month, date.day, date.year, date.hour, date.minute, date.second)
'7 23, 2013 2:44:44'
```

**OR** A better way would be to use the `datetime.datetime.strftime` method, like follows

```
>>> date.strftime("%m %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
'07 23, 2013 02:44:44'
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to record this so how do I get it to return as a string?  7 23 2013 4 44 44

Comment: @viralsolanki : Added a better way using `strftime`. :)

Comment: I just needed to write it to excel. I did just inputted it into the writer as is and it worked well